# where is visual studio 2013 find search textbox in toolbar

Tags: visual-studio, textbox, find, toolbar

It is so painful for me to "Ctrl+F" keys to open search or find text box in Visual Studio 2013. So how to I put this text box back to tool bar and click on it when I need?

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely you will see a small folder with magnified class icon in the tool bar attached is the image.

Click on the dropdown menu next to it to the right and select what  you want to add permanently to your toolbar menu.

[image]